# Math functions for GPS coordinates

Tags: math, gps, coordinates

Is there any repository of math functions focused on the GPS coordinates system? (latitude, longitude)

I am looking for:

- Distance between two points
- Distance from point to line
- Obtain mirror point D: Given a line from A to B and the point C, obtain the point D, which has the distance to the line as C. (on the same plane):

[image: mirror point]

I will implement it in php, although that it's not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

These are basically normal functions...

Have a look at http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html .

This site was a big help for me understanding the mathematic background of the calculations.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that [PROJ](https://proj.org/) to be brilliant for this kind of work. It also allows you to convert between ellipsoid approximations (such as WGS84 commonly used by GPS) and a plethora of map projections. There's a simple C library for use in a program of your own.

It's under a very liberal license.